# Handsontable - rowspan/merge rowheaders?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

Using Handsontable, how would I merge two rowheaders or give them a rowspan of two, so they fit over two rows?

[Example Link](http://rallen.dk/newtable2.php)

Screenshot:

[image]